# Can access web server from lan, but not internet

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, apache-http-server, webserver, snow-leopard-server

Right, well as the title says really.

OS X Snow Leopard web server, all the latest updates.

I can connect it to it on the LAN, but not on any external ISP...sorta.

Can't connect to the domain on port 80, however I can connect to the site using port 443 with ssl, by going with Https instead of Http.

I can ping the domain happily. I can also ping the IP. And the IP also resolves to the domain.

So I'm thinking it's something in the Apache config, or OS X. However I have looked in httpd.conf and can't see anything askew.

So I'm pretty stuck. Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you can connect to it from the LAN, are you on that machine or a different computer? If you're on that machine, then it could be that your apache config file is listening to port 80 only on 127.0.0.1 (loopback). If you're able to see it from another computer, check and make sure that your firewall/router is pointing port 80 to that server's local IP.

Comment: Different machines, on the LAN.